# MCMC for estimating negative binomial distribution

Tags: r, optimization, random, mcmc

I want to estimate parameters of negative binomial distribution using MCMC Metropolis-Hastings algorithm. In other words, I have sample:

```
set.seed(42)
y <- rnbinom(20, size = 3, prob = 0.2)
```

and I want to write algorithm that will estimate parameter of size and parameter of prob.

**My work so far**

I defined prior distribution of size as Poisson:

```
prior_r <- function(r) {
  return(dpois(r, lambda = 2, log = T))
}
```

And prior distribution of prob as uniform on [0, 1]:

```
prior_prob <- function(prob) {
  return(dunif(prob, min = 0, max = 1, log = T))
}
```

Moreover for simplicity I defined loglikelihood and joint probability functions:

```
loglikelihood <- function(data, r, prob) {
  loglikelihoodValue <- sum(dnorm(data, mean = r, sd = prob, log = T))
  return(loglikelihoodValue)
}


joint <- function(r, prob) {
  data <- y
  return(loglikelihood(data, r, prob) + prior_r(r) + prior_prob(prob))
}
```

Finally, the whole algorithm:

```
run_mcmc <- function(startvalue, iterations) {
  
  chain <- array(dim = c(iterations + 1, 2))

  chain[1, ] <- startvalue

  for (i in 1:iterations) {

    proposal_r <- rpois(1, lambda = chain[i, 1])

    proposal_prob <- chain[i, 2] + runif(1, min = -0.2, max = 0.2)
    
    quotient <- joint(proposal_r, proposal_prob) - joint(chain[i, 1], chain[i, 2])
    
    if (runif(1, 0, 1) < min(1, exp(quotient))) chain[i + 1, ] <- c(proposal_r, proposal_prob)
    
    else chain[i + 1, ] <- chain[i, ]

  }

  return(chain)
}
```

**The problem**

Problem that I'm having is that when I run it with starting values even very close to correct ones:

```
iterations <- 2000
startvalue <- c(4, 0.25)
res <- run_mcmc(startvalue, iterations)
```

I'll obtain posterior distribution which is obviously wrong. For example

```
> colMeans(res)
[1] 11.963018  0.994533
```

As you can see, size is located very close to point 12, and probability is located in point 1.

Do you know what's the cause of those phenomeons?

Comment: do you want to know what is causing those phenomenon's programmatically or mathematically? If you are more interested in the math side, then stat exchange might be a better place to post the question.

Comment: Why `dnorm` in `loglikelihood` instead of `dnbinom`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `dnorm` in `loglikelihood` to `dnbinom` and fix the proposal for `prob` so it doesn't go outside (0,1):

```
set.seed(42)
y <- rnbinom(20, size = 3, prob = 0.2)

prior_r <- function(r) {
  return(dpois(r, lambda = 2, log = T))
}

prior_prob <- function(prob) {
  return(dunif(prob, min = 0, max = 1, log = TRUE))
}

loglikelihood <- function(data, r, prob) {
  loglikelihoodValue <- sum(dnbinom(data, size = r, prob = prob, log = TRUE))
  return(loglikelihoodValue)
}

joint <- function(r, prob) {
  return(loglikelihood(y, r, prob) + prior_r(r) + prior_prob(prob))
}

run_mcmc <- function(startvalue, iterations) {
  
  chain <- array(dim = c(iterations + 1, 2))
  
  chain[1, ] <- startvalue
  
  for (i in 1:iterations) {
    proposal_r <- rpois(1, lambda = chain[i, 1])
    proposal_prob <- chain[i, 2] + runif(1, min = max(-0.2, -chain[i,2]), max = min(0.2, 1 - chain[i,2]))
    quotient <- joint(proposal_r, proposal_prob) - joint(chain[i, 1], chain[i, 2])
    
    if (runif(1, 0, 1) < min(1, exp(quotient))) {
      chain[i + 1, ] <- c(proposal_r, proposal_prob)
    } else {
      chain[i + 1, ] <- chain[i, ]
    }
  }
  
  return(chain)
}

iterations <- 2000
startvalue <- c(4, 0.25)
res <- run_mcmc(startvalue, iterations)
colMeans(res)
#> [1] 3.1009495 0.1988177
```